# Poisson regression with random effect using pre-post data

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, poisson-regression

I have data on outcomes collected across several clinics. The outcome is an integer indicating days until treatment initiation. Outcome data were collected at baseline and follow up, and are collected for multiple patients during each period. Note that patients are not followed (ie, patients at baseline are not the same patients in follow up).

Some clinics had an intervention (which is expected to reduce the time to treatment initiation), some did not. The intervention was implemented between baseline and follow up.

I would like to assess whether the intervention (1) reduced the number of days to receiving test results compared to clinics that did not have the intervention, and (2) reduced time from baseline to follow up among intervention clinics.

Assuming no over dispersion in the data:

- To answer the first question, my plan was to run Poisson regression
  among only those in follow up, with the intervention arm as a fixed
  effect and clinic as a random effect.
- To answer the second question, my plan was to run Poisson regression
  among only those receiving the intervention with period (ie, baseline/follow up) as a fixed effect and clinic as a random effect

Is this the most appropriate approach to answer these questions? Any and all advice is much appreciated.

---

###### Some helpful information

1. A visual representation of the data, with light red clinics receiving the intervention, and grey clinics not receiving the intervention.

[image]

2. The data are structured like this. Note that the patients are a running count of patients for each clinic at each time point (here, each clinic has 2 at each time point) and not a formal ID number (ie, patient 1 at baseline is not the same a patient 1 at follow up).

| clinic | arm | period | patient | days_till_tx |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | intervention | Baseline | 1 | 6 |
| A | intervention | Baseline | 2 | 10 |
| A | intervention | Follow Up | 1 | 7 |
| A | intervention | Follow Up | 2 | 11 |
| B | control | Baseline | 1 | 13 |
| B | control | Baseline | 2 | 4 |
| B | control | Follow Up | 1 | 8 |
| B | control | Follow Up | 2 | 12 |
| C | intervention | Baseline | 1 | 8 |
| C | intervention | Baseline | 2 | 8 |
| C | intervention | Follow Up | 1 | 13 |
| C | intervention | Follow Up | 2 | 8 |
| D | control | Baseline | 1 | 9 |
| D | control | Baseline | 2 | 8 |
| D | control | Follow Up | 1 | 5 |
| D | control | Follow Up | 2 | 12 |

3. Reproducible R code:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(clinic = rep(LETTERS[1:4], each = 4),
                 arm = rep(c("intervention", "control"), each = 4),
                 period = rep(c("Baseline", "Follow Up"), each = 2),
                 patient = rep(1:2),
                 days_till_tx = rpois(16, lambda = 8))
# Q1 model
mdl1 <- lme4::glmer(days_till_tx ~ arm + (1|clinic), 
                   data = df[df$period %in% "Follow Up",], 
                   family = poisson(link = "log"))
# Q2 model
mdl2 <- lme4::glmer(days_till_tx ~ period + (1|clinic), 
                   data = df[df$arm %in% "intervention",], 
                   family = poisson(link = "log"))
```